# I am getting an permission error with azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

On my Storage account my access of Azure AD has been removed

[image]

[image]

although on IAM i am able to see my Azure AD as a owner

Can you help me on this

Comment: Owner role won't help you here. You need Storage Blob Contributor role to manage data inside a storage account. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs

Answer (score 1):

> This is an execepted behaviour when you have `owner` permission.

To resolve this issue you need to have: `Storage Blob Data Contributor` which grant read/write/delete permissions to Blob storage resources.

[image]

For more details, refer to [Authorize access to blobs using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs).

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to access the blob, As I got below result.**

[image]

If you have **Owner** role on storage account, it should work only with **Authentication method** **Access key** not with **Azure AD User Account**

In order to authenticate with **Azure AD User Account**, kindly assign **Storage Blob Contributor** role to your account.

Once I assign the **Storage Blob Contributor** role to my account, I'm able to access the container.

[image]

Thanks to **Gaurav Mantri** for suggesting the same.